# provider shared module angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a service that is set as part of a shared module e.g.

```
export class MyService { 
    construct() { }...
}

export class CoreModule {

    constructor(@optional() @SkipSelf() core: CoreModule)
    {
        if (core)
        { 
            throw new Error('Only one instances')
        }
    }

    static forRoot() : ModuleWithProviders {
        return{
            ngModule: CoreModule,
            providers: [MyService]
        };
    }
}
```

I want to inject this CoreModule (share as singleton) to different module that will use the myService.

Scenario - component A is loading e.g. component B dynamically

One my component is dynamically loading another component view, using the  viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory), it seems to create a new instance of the CoreModule, but I need this to be a singleton or the service to be a singleton, when it get injected into component A, but component B seems to be creating a new instances, I have value already set when the app component loads .

Comment: This is not possible, If you want to share all over module then you have to set as provider into app module

Comment: Is this CoreModule lazy loaded, or is it coming in right away and imported in app.module.ts?

Comment: I have the CoreModule loaded into app.module.ts and CoreModule.forRoot()

Comment: I ended  up making myService to be singleton (as static), that way it can be easily reference throughout the application. Shared Module etc. does not work with Lazy loading module, as they get their own context, and any provider will initialized